# Wcsession session expired and error 7007

Tags: swift, watchkit, wcsession

I am new in WatchKit and I am working on one of my app, but I am facing one problem regarding connection with Apple watch.

my source code is below:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ //create a session using wcsession    
    if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
        [[WCSession defaultSession] setDelegate:self];
        [[WCSession defaultSession] activateSession];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Send message action in my viewcontroller:

```
[[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:dict replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *replyHandler)
{        
    NSLog(@"Replay %@",replyHandler);
}
errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error %@",error);  
}];
```

Also I activate the wcsession at watch side in complication controller

```
]if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
    [[WCSession defaultSession] setDelegate:self];
    [[WCSession defaultSession] activateSession];
}
```

and

```
-(void)session:(nonnull WCSession *)session
    didReceiveMessage:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message
    replyHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * __nonnull))replyHandler {
    [extensionDelgate InsertIntoTideMaster:message];
    [self requestedUpdateDidBegin];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{           
    });
}
```

This works first time when I am launching the app, but after that I got 7007 code error ... can you tell me what is missing here?

Thanks in advance.